# Automatic mailing service after insertion of record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am working on a website and I want to send an otp to the after the user registers. So I want to save the otp in the table first along with the other details of the user and later I want to send the otp to the user using the trigger. Will it be possible to send the otp through email using trigger.
please guide me how to do that.

Is there any other way to do that if yes please let me know how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

Since you provided only superficial information my answer will be of the same kind.

Since you are executing PHP code to do whatever you are doing you can make a function like

```
function sendMyMail($recipient, $message, $subject);
```

and implement it somewhere.
To actually send the mail in this function I recomment [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). There are examples and much more.
On a note: You need an existing SMTP Client, any existing and working E-Mail Address should do. The PHP Mailer will use this mail to send your mails automatically. Implementing an own solution without an existing E-Mail will take about a couple of weeks I would say (Maybe not but it is really complicated)

**EDIT:**
This is how I send mails with PHP Mailer

```
function sendMail($recipients, $subject, $message, $altMessage)
{
    if(dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "/")
    {
        require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    }
    else
    {
        require "../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    }

    //testXSS is a custom Function
    $subject = testXSS($subject);
    $message = nl2br($message);//To display line breaks in HTML

    $recipients = explode(",", $recipients);//$recipients is a comma seperater string of email addresses

    $amountRecipients = count($recipients);

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers, sometimes this is also mail.example.com or something else
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "yourAdress@example.com";             // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "SomeStrongPassword";                 // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                              // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = "a number, depending on your settings";   // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";                               // Set charset to utf-8

    $mail->setFrom("noreply@example.com", "NOREPLY");

    for($i = 0; $i < $amountRecipients; $i++)
    {
        $mail->addAddress($recipients[$i]);                 //optional: Name as second param, not used here
    }

    $mail->addReplyTo("noreply@example.com", "Noreply");

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                    // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = "Whatever: ".$subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;                              //Any Mail content. Can include HTML Code
    $mail->AltBody = $altMessage;                           //If the recipient does not display HTML Mails this should not contain HTML Code

    $result = ($mail->send());

    if($result)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $comment = "What went wrong";
        writeToLog("DESCRIPTION", $comment);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do u actually want to know more about my question as u said its not that sufficient.

Comment: I mean that Stackoverflow is not meant to deliver tutorials or step by step solutions. If you have code that does not work or not how you want it to this is the place for you. But if you are looking for a tutorial you are better of with google and other platforms. Since you asked whether it is possible I answered this question and gave you links on where to go to get to the point you want to. And I wrote superficial, not sufficient :)

Comment: okay sorry for that, my bad. I have seen a lot of codes and I cant even understand that what they have written actually as I never worked with automated mails. So i asked u in the question in that manner.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Mails are really a pain in the ass. They can be very tedious to deal with. If you want I can post my code on how I send mails but this might not be entirely what you need...

Comment: I ll be pleased if u post the code what u actually use.

Comment: ok, give me a few minutes

Comment: I added some code. I use PHP Mailer for this. If you find this helpful I would be happy about an upvote :) If you have further questions do not hesitate to ask :)

Comment: I ll go through the code once and if I have any doubts I ll ask you for sure.